# Assigning a Matlab vector according to a function

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I basically want to vectorize the following:

```
vect_y = zeros(1,numel(vect_x);
for i = 1:numel(vect_x)
    vect_y = sum(vect_x(1:i));
end
```

Is this possible? As an example, I was trying to use arrayfun the following way:

```
y = arrayfun(@(y) sum(y), vect_x(1:1), vect_x(1:2), ..., vect_x(1:n));
```

But this won't work and it's not clean.

edit:
So I know now that cumsum solves the above, but I am curious as to how I would do this for any function.

Comment: Looks like you want to do a cummulative sum: [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done with the [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) function directly:

```
vect_y = cumsum(vect_x);
```